# Update Query - multiple row in same table SQL Server

Tags: sql

I want to create query which will update TimeStamp column and write data in it from another column `DateOfInsert` (for each row data in column `DateOfInsert` is different)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, probably something like this will do it:

```
UPDATE your_table t 
SET t.TimeStamp = t.DateOfInsert 
WHERE t.DateOfInsert <> t.TimeStamp
```

But this will update every row in the table, is this what you want ?

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE table t SET t.TimeStamp=t.DateOfInsert
```

Comment: This is not considering RedStar's needs. Delete your answer or add a WHERE clause.